# I can't get my color primary to match the buttons on my screen even though they are the same HEX color in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, user-interface, hex

I can't get my colors in my app to line up, even though they supposedly are the same hex code. What I did is I went into Sketch (where I exported and made the buttons) and used the program to get hex code, but as you can see from the picture (below that is not the same color.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZdzI.jpg

Here is my code from my colors file and styles file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
<color name= "color1"> #5AD7DB</color>
<color name= "color2"> #D53D96</color>
<color name= "color3"> #F27E33</color>


</resources>

<resources>
```

Here is my styles file

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color1</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color1</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomHelpshiftTheme" 
 parent="Helpshift.Theme.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color2</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color1</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color1</item>
</style>

<style name="Helpshift.Theme.Base" parent="MyCustomHelpshiftTheme"/>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code in your colors.xml file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
  <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
  <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
  <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
  <color name="color1">#5AD7DB</color>
  <color name="color2">#D53D96</color>
<color name="color3">#F27E33</color>


  </resources>
```

Spaces removed where unnecessary..